# How to have text closer to image?

Tags: html, css

I've been fiddling around with Css and got to have my text and image be responsive on mobile. When I shrink my browser the image the text shrinks to show the image, but now my lorem ipsum text is pushed down. I'm not using padding or margin for this to happen, I'm trying to keep all of my text in a div but there seems to be alot of margin on text.

I've looked over my code and couldn't find anything that would cause this, and delete each segment of code to try and see if it fixes the problem. Nothing seems to work.

html:

```
<body>

    <table >
    <tr>
        <td >Home</td> <!--Made 8 boxes, 100%/8boxes is 12.5, so to make them even just assign 12.5%-->
        <td >About Us</td> <!--Can see how CSS comes in handy...could just call td{width:12.5%; align:center;-->
        <td`enter code here` >Contact Us</td>
        <td >Menus</td>
        <td >Varieties</td>
        <td >Feedback</td>
        <td >SignUp</td>
        <td >Login</td> 
    </tr>
    </table>

    <p id="mainWall"></p>
    <h1 class="mImageText">Paratore's Pizza</h1>


    <p>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum deleniti incidunt iusto architecto animi dolore cum quod modi earum, nisi est aspernatur quibusdam iure eos cumque necessitatibus distinctio iste aperiam.
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum deleniti incidunt iusto architecto animi dolore cum quod modi earum, nisi est aspernatur quibusdam iure eos cumque necessitatibus distinctio iste aperiam.
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum deleniti incidunt iusto architecto animi dolore cum quod modi earum, nisi est aspernatur quibusdam iure eos cumque necessitatibus distinctio iste aperiam.
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum deleniti incidunt iusto architecto animi dolore cum quod modi earum, nisi est aspernatur quibusdam iure eos cumque necessitatibus distinctio iste aperiam.
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum deleniti incidunt iusto architecto animi dolore cum quod modi earum, nisi est aspernatur quibusdam iure eos cumque necessitatibus distinctio iste aperiam.
    </p>


</body>
</html>


table{
    width:100%;  
}

td{
    height: 100px;
    color:white;
    background-color: #c40909;
    text-align: center;
    width: 12.5%;
    border-radius: 22px;
    font-size: 25px;
}

td:hover{
    background-color: #ff9a26;
    transform: scale(.9, .9);
}

#mainWall{

    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto; 
    text-align: center;
    height: 75vh;

    width: 100%;
    background: url(images/mainWall.jpg);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: bottom bottom;
      background-position: center center;


      background-attachment: scroll;
      background-size:cover;
      border-radius: 20px;
}

.mImageText {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-175%);
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Russo One', sans-serif;
    font-size: 9vw;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 1;
    letter-spacing: 2vw; 
    text-shadow: 10px 15px #a80303;
    }
```

I expect the text to come closer to the image instead of being all the way down requiring a scroll

Answer (score 0):

Your `mImageText` class has a translateY of -175%. This, plus the height of the `mainWall` class is causing the gap. Try changing the height of `mainWall` to something smaller, like `10vh`, and remove the translateY from `mImageText`

Comment: I see that when I remove the translate it returns it to the original position and that's what's causing this, I'm simply trying to have text over an image and that's what's messing me up

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate? Are you saying the translateY is necessary? You could always give your text `<p>` tag a unique id, then set it's position to absolute and give it a negative top-margin. A bit hacky, yes, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about some of your rules. I have removed the following 2 rules - those are making the problem:

```
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-175%);
```

```css
table{
    width:100%;  
}

td{
    height: 100px;
    color:white;
    background-color: #c40909;
    text-align: center;
    width: 12.5%;
    border-radius: 22px;
    font-size: 25px;
}

td:hover{
    background-color: #ff9a26;
    transform: scale(.9, .9);
}

#mainWall{

    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto; 
    text-align: center;

    width: 100%;
    background: url(images/mainWall.jpg);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: bottom bottom;
      background-position: center center;


      background-attachment: scroll;
      background-size:cover;
      border-radius: 20px;
}

.mImageText {
    position: relative;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Russo One', sans-serif;
    font-size: 9vw;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 1;
    letter-spacing: 2vw; 
    text-shadow: 10px 15px #a80303;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<body>

    <table >
    <tr>
        <td >Home</td> <!--Made 8 boxes, 100%/8boxes is 12.5, so to make them even just assign 12.5%-->
        <td >About Us</td> <!--Can see how CSS comes in handy...could just call td{width:12.5%; align:center;-->
        <td>Contact Us</td>
        <td >Menus</td>
        <td >Varieties</td>
        <td >Feedback</td>
        <td >SignUp</td>
        <td >Login</td> 
    </tr>
    </table>

    <p id="mainWall"></p>
    <h1 class="mImageText">Paratore's Pizza</h1>


    <p>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum deleniti incidunt iusto architecto animi dolore cum quod modi earum, nisi est aspernatur quibusdam iure eos cumque necessitatibus distinctio iste aperiam.
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum deleniti incidunt iusto architecto animi dolore cum quod modi earum, nisi est aspernatur quibusdam iure eos cumque necessitatibus distinctio iste aperiam.
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum deleniti incidunt iusto architecto animi dolore cum quod modi earum, nisi est aspernatur quibusdam iure eos cumque necessitatibus distinctio iste aperiam.
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum deleniti incidunt iusto architecto animi dolore cum quod modi earum, nisi est aspernatur quibusdam iure eos cumque necessitatibus distinctio iste aperiam.
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum deleniti incidunt iusto architecto animi dolore cum quod modi earum, nisi est aspernatur quibusdam iure eos cumque necessitatibus distinctio iste aperiam.
    </p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah I'm looking up a tutorial I think I'm just over thinking how to simply add text over an image...

Answer (score 0):

One way to keep your lorem ipsum text closer to the elements above it is to put a `class` or `id` on that paragraph. Then give it a negative `top-margin`:

CSS:

```
   #lorem {
    margin-top: -8em;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<p id = "lorem">
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum deleniti incidunt iusto architecto animi dolore cum quod modi earum, nisi est aspernatur quibusdam iure eos cumque necessitatibus distinctio iste aperiam.
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum deleniti incidunt iusto architecto animi dolore cum quod modi earum, nisi est aspernatur quibusdam iure eos
    </p>
```